# Can it affect me negatively if I upvote too much?

Tags: discussion, support

I have been thinking about this problem, since I joined Stackoverflow community.

I can use up to 40 votes each day. So far, in the two months I've been registered, I have only used 33.
The reason for that is, that I observed some high reputation users that haven't even used 40 votes in over a year.
Suppose I start using *all* my votes Daily. Does it make my profile and me look BAD?

I also have some more concerns:

1. Does upvoting a bad question/answer, makes me look bad in eyes of Moderators and Security bots?
2. Does having a lot of upvotes on your record make you look less intelligent and less upvotes make you look like more of a bright guy?
3. (linked to 1) What if I thought a question was good for me, but wasn't good for someone else, does that make my upvote look bad?
4. The decrease in the upvoting is related to the increase in less interesting questions. But then, does no upvoting makes even the dumb guys look intelligent and vice versa?
5. Is there any Penalty on any worse case scenario for upvote?

These concerns often prevent me from upvoting.

Comment: You only seem to be talking about upvoting. Whatever you do: vote but please also down vote the low quality/useless/wrong stuff.

Comment: You are free to use your votes the way you see fit, provided you vote on the post content and not on a user (no *targeted voting*, especially not for friends or colleagues). Using all your votes does not lead to penalties. Voting is a crucial part of how the site works, and *this includes downvoting*. Downvoting is not used enough on the site, please considered **downvoting on bad content**.

Comment: Upvoting surfaces *good content*. If and when you actually find good content, by all means, do upvote it. But please try to be discerning about what really is and isn't good.

Comment: I want to add something here, not that i appeal it, but just for a matter of noticing, why the question has 0 upvotes but answer has 5, and i think this question relates the main question, if wrong, please clarify.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really worrying about here. You've only ever cast _33_ votes, according to your profile.

Comment: That's why I asked this question, because I don't like low upvotes on my profile, people must be awarded for there hard work. but it is turning out 40/day votes are more than enough

Comment: Why this question received fewer upvotes than the answer… because people don't find it particularly interesting or worth upvoting, but they're enthralled with the excellent answer to it nonetheless. Voting works on each individual post and should always be done without context.

Comment: I've attempted to clarify the question a bit.

Comment: @Deceze, I understand the different point of views, but in case of hard work, both deserves the same, or the question precedes the answer, because it opens up new ways of thinking, but again i don't think it's unfair.

Comment: @Syed SO is a meritocracy, not an *everybody-get-a-price* system. Just "hard work" isn't always worth upvoting. :o)

Comment: I am more than thankful for your useful time, and the matter is clear enough for me, not to question anymore on this topic.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That is true, but unless they changed it, downvoting costs you rep, and any lower rep user is not going to want to downvote many posts simply because getting rep is generally hard. If i down voted every time I wanted to, I would be unable to comment. Earning rep is difficult on stack overflow unless you are an expert in at least moderately popular programming languages/tools/frameworks. With the massive amount of down vote worth posts being added, its impossible to make that deficit up for most people.

Comment: I'm surprised no-one mentioned that indiscriminate up-voting can make bad content hard to get rid of. Even one up-vote can stop a question that no-one wants to entertain from being deleted by the [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

Comment: @Ryan: downvoting questions is entirely free. Downvoting an answer costs you *one point*. Even a question upvote easily earns you rep for 5 downvotes.

Comment: Just in case you (or future viewers) missed it: **you should be downvoting low quality content**

Comment: the op doesn't have the rep to cast downvotes.

Comment: The OP should get more rep then

Comment: heh, "security bots"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> Does upvoting a bad question/answer, makes me look bad in eyes of Moderators and Security BOTS ?

Not that is publicly known at this moment.

Moderators cannot directly see who or what you voted on. They will only be alerted if there's an indication of vote *abuse* - like, you voting a lot on a certain person's posts, or creating new accounts for voting up your own contributions ("sock puppets").

Other than that, the system will not punish you for upvoting "too much".

Of course, that doesn't mean you should ever be upvoting bad questions and answers.

> Do having a lot of upvotes record make you less intelligent and less upvotes make you more of a bright guy?

Not *necessarily*. There are some very smart people on Stack Overflow who make a point of only upvoting good content they see, and not using downvotes at all because they feel it's negative/rude/hostile. I don't agree with them at all: downvoting is the most powerful quality control we have. At 12,000+ new questions every day, that is *important*.

But the system will not punish them.

There can be social consequences though. If you have *only* upvotes in your profile, some people (including myself) might look at you funny.

If you ever want to become an elected moderator, people will look at your voting record and might question your judgement and fitness to be a moderator. Moderators are expected to do quality control and that means closing down bad and off topic content. A voting record with no downvotes could look to some like you're not able to do that unpleasant job.

There's no consequences apart from that, though.

> What if I thought a question was good for me, but wasn't good for someone else, Does that look my upvote look bad ?

No one can see who upvoted a post, so there's no way for you to look bad.

Also, you have every right to vote as you please (as long as you're not voting fraudulently, see above).

However, it's certainly important to consider whether a post is actually good and healthy for the community, too, and not just for yourself. A post can contain good info for me, or be a *great* question, but be completely off topic for the site. What I often do in such cases is neither cast an upvote nor a downvote (but vote to close if appropriate).

So - no, there are no automated penalties for voting "wrongly". Only social consequences.

It's still a good thing to vote responsibly, and not forget to downvote bad content.

Comment: I am delighted for having your answer, But with no disrespect and pure facts:
In a Year, I almost has 14600 for upvote, and in 7 years, it would be 102200. Now if I suppose you as a standard for myself, you only have upvoted 3386 votes in 7 years, which is the 3rd of only a year.
What I want to say, suppose i have clever upvotes 10000 a year and is being compared to you, What that makes me look like?
I am deeply apologize for any disconfort.

Comment: @Syed you would have to look at my [Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka-웃) to compare - I have roughly 12,000 upvotes and 11,000 downvotes. The numbers don't really matter, though: the voting record is not that important. Just try to provide good questions and answers, upvote when you see good content, and downvote when you see bad content. If you can honestly say you always voted responsibly, that's great and nothing else is needed. Don't worry too much about what voting makes you look like.

Comment: *"There are some very smart people on Stack Overflow who make a point of only upvoting good content they see, and not using downvotes at all because they feel it's negative/rude/hostile."* And there also exists [the converse](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert?tab=topactivity), with only 1 upvote ever (rumored to be an accident), but lots of downvotes.

Comment: I am very thankful guys for your great help and time, for someone like me, who has just joined the community. The matter is clear to me now, and no further help is needed on this matter.

Comment: Downvoting is not the answer. Most users on this site are stingy with their upvotes. You have 300K reputation and have only upvoted 12K times. A whopping reputation deficit. If a question is worth your time to answer, it should deserve an upvote.

Comment: @Aducci that whole comment is false. Downvoting _is_ the answer to bad content, just as upvoting is the answer to good content. Depending on what tags you contribute to, you will find varying degrees of difficulty in gathering upvotes. 12K upvotes is IMO quite a lot. I have personally cast ~1500 upvotes and ~5000 downvotes in almost two years. I often answer questions that lack research effort or are otherwise undeserving of an upvote. I have even answered questions that I've downvoted. I will never answer a question and vote to close it at the same time though.

Comment: @Aducci not that I agree with your argument, but not sure I follow your math? 7,000 answers, 12,000 upvotes, where is the "deficit"?

Comment: @Pekka웃 - A reputation deficit. You have received more reputation than you have given out: Upvoting  < 120K, bounties ~= 16K, OP accepting your answer < 14K, accepting answers to your questions < 4K.

Comment: @Aducci to call that a "deficit" makes about as much sense as Donald Trump's belief that having a trade deficit with another country means your own country is being taken advantage of.

Answer (score -19):

You shouldn't care my friend. In these days with the trolls and reputation seeking moderators stackoverflow's reputation loses it's once valid  benchmark. Actually your question indicates that you are searching for best ways to increase the reputation of your profile. The next question you will be asking is for which behaviour favours you and about the "leaks" in the system ... which will turn you in to the corrupted person most moderators nowadays here are.

Good luck if that's your way, mine and upvoters of this post surely not.

Comment: At Least you are straight forward, that I can say for sure. Other than that, I don't know exactly about corruption in this community. If you could give me a hint, I would ask about it.

Comment: There are no "reputation seeking moderators" because there are no moderators who care about reputation. Of course, this answer is not *complete* nonsense. It is true that you shouldn't care because reputation is largely a meaningless number.

Comment: Downvoting and closevoting don't accumulate reputation. People who are interested only in reputation are, hence, unlikely to participate in those activities

Comment: More often than not, people with a lot of good reputation are helpful and have posted and responded to a lot of issues. It's clear to see that it's not easy to accumulate reputation and it does mean something. I know that when I get a good response from a higher rep person, often it is correct and knowledgable. It's a good way to keep people from coming to this site, registering an account and then leaving some junk information. I value the high bar and drive for accuracy on this website, else I'd be trawling the github forums or elsewhere for technical solutions instead of here...Word.