# Do users who participate in Meta have more profile visits from moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderation, users, moderators

I have a feeling, after asking a few questions on Meta, that more Moderators will visit your Stack Overflow profile, as a result of participating here. Let me support my argument, with the history of questions I've posted.

[I asked about viewing rejected edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343360/most-asked-question-unclear-viewing-rejected-edits), where I mentioned that I have edited some posts. [The second answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343366/) says "*After glancing through a few of your recent edits*...". I wholeheartedly welcomed the answer, and applied the advice immediately.

After a few more edits, I got another comment from that answerer saying *"I see you haven't really taken the guidelines to heart"*. This was the point where I felt an eye was being kept on me, because of Meta.

A few hours Later, I received a message from a diamond moderator, to stop the persistent errors in my edits. The moderator also mentioned the poster of that Meta answer, who asked me before about my problem. I guessed, that it would not be possible for the moderators to go to each account and check edits daily, and this made me strongly feel that I must be getting attention from Meta. I thanked him for his time, and started to follow the rules exactly.

Yesterday, I asked [a question which definitely pointed towards too much upvoting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343468/can-it-affect-me-negatively-if-i-upvote-too-much), and hours later, I received a message from the moderator stating *"noticed a substantial number of votes on your account to or from specific users"*, and they were right. I had upvoted 3 answers of my friend five days ago, but I didn't feel good about it, and tried to remove the vote, but it was locked. This led me to ask this question on Meta. It was a very good thing to do on the moderator's part, but again I wondered, wasn't this because I asked a question about too much upvoting.

My profile views have increased from 8 to 52, which I presume were by the moderators to check my profile out, although some of them may have been from the people whose posts I edited.

**Based on the assumptions that I have about more attention coming from Meta posts**, I want this to be discussed in two broad categories:

1. Yes, it's true.
2. No, it's not true.

Although it's just a yes or no, it is connected to a big discussion, if answered. This question is asked for the sole purpose of understanding the community better, and to make a good contribution towards it. Telling me the answer is "yes" is good, because I'll learn something.

Comment: By "moderators" do you mean users with moderating privileges (i.e., anyone with 15 rep or more) or do you mean elected diamond mods or SE employees, or what?

Comment: I meant Elected diamond mods or SE employees.

Comment: Moderators probably have better things to do than spend their time looking at the behaviour of users participating on Meta. You asked 6 questions here in 2-3 days. That certainly will get you noticed by the community as a whole. Depending on your behaviour that can result in flags if certain things are (or seem) out of order, which moderators will then handle. But overall, no, I do not see why moderators would spend their time on you just because you participate here. P.s. profile views are not just from moderators.

Comment: @Bart (1) noticed by community because of meta answer (YES),  then you said No. And you also skipped answering, any of the five questions directly. Please do submit an answer, with a proper answer to each question.

Comment: You're asking about the behaviour of elected diamond moderators or SE employees. I'm saying that while the community as a whole may notice your activities, moderators do not go out of their way to look at you or investigate your behaviour. But not being a diamond moderator, nor an employee, let's see if they provide some input. A comment is a comment because it's not an answer.

Comment: Community cannot trace behaviours like these of each member. It's just common sense. Question 1,2 propose a non moderator member flagging my meta question to the moderator, which as a result caused a message from him.
So point remains the same, tracking starts from posting in meta.

Comment: Starting from the general community. That does however not seem to be your question. If it is, clarify your question. For now, you seem to be asking whether or not employees and elected moderators pay more attention to you and your activities just because you post on Meta. I'm hard pressed to believe that is the case.

Comment: Clearly you are confusing moderators with "users that research your question".  Good Q+A requires research.  Such users tend to have enough rep to have some moderation rights, like editing without review and posting close and delete votes, the inevitable side-effect of posting well-researched answers.  And a subset visits Meta regularly, they care about the site.

Comment: Yes, maybe, but do knew that a person (in Q2) who has enough reputation, caused a moderator to send me a message. But my question remains the same, Does Stackoverflow account affect, because someone has posted a question in meta?

Comment: Not "someone".  You.  They look at your profile to see your usage habits, might be relevant to your question.  It will be when you ask about voting practices.  Just normal research and the basic reason your profile is visible to users.

Comment: That was a regular user checking up on you to see if you took the advice to heart. You apparently didn't, and [you still don't](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15176778). With edit reviewing being as problematic as it is, we don't need to make the issue worse by people making poor edits when they have been informed about them. Some users may be so concerned about this that they follow up on the situation, just hoping you'll pick up their advice.

Comment: You [asked a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343248/profile-picture-changed-in-gmail-not-reflected-on-stack-overflow) specifically about your profile photo, it shouldn't be too big a surprise that profile views went up.

Comment: Thank you for answering question 5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are certain kinds of meta posts that invite moderator scrutiny, but meta participation by itself should not lead to any increased moderator attention.

There are some kinds of meta posts that invite moderators and other users to take a look at your profile. The most common type are probably complaints about votes, or the reputation system in general. To respond to them, you generally need to take a look at the profile of the asker. And if a moderator does that, they'll also notice if that user has been doing any questionable voting, or is part of a sock network.

There are other kinds of meta questions and behaviour that subtly indicate that a user might be causing some kind of issue. For example, if a user behaves aggresively on meta, odds are that at least one meta user will quickly check if that user also did the same thing on the main site.

There are many common patterns to problematic user behaviour on SE, and experienced regular users and moderators have seen some of them often enough that they'll quickly recognize certain signs. It's a kind of crude pattern matching, that does tend to work surprisingly well.

Comment: While I appreciate, this profile checking due to a post on meta, Don't you think, it leaves the impression of, "NOT posting on meta", just because no one wants, their mistakes to be shown to entire world..!

Comment: In general not. It entirely depends on which questions you ask and on how many of them. I also checked your profile some days ago when you asked about rejected edits (how else should one get an opinion about it?). Also asking a lot of questions in short time might get some users to check your profile to see whether there is a fundamental problem there. Also, if would have just seen this question and your comments here: Your comments are sometimes a bit harsh (from the point of a non-native speaker), so I would have checked whether your comments on SO are in the same style.

Comment: Thank you for your time, the matter is clear to me now

Answer (score 7):

No, moderators will not visit your profile just because you participate on Meta.

But your participation on Meta does lead to the many scrutinizing eyes of the regular users and there are a lot of them. They will visit your profile, specially when you ask a bunch of meta questions about different aspects in short time. That puts you in the spotlight for all topics asked.

Each of these users have their special pet peeve and they will either point out to you what needs be improved or flag for a moderator when they spot something suspicious. Those flags make that moderators land on your profile and if they find the raised flag valid, they might investigate a bit further if they see reason for that.

Keep in mind that having this attention is not per se a good thing. This can be evaded by re-reading the [Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help) (shortcut keys: g e) or search on Meta or on the [Über Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and apply guidance to the best of your abilities before taking an action be it on main or meta.

One last thing: when I leave a comment like *"I see you haven't really taken the guidelines to heart"* do realize it isn't meant to be supportive or that I keep an good an eye on you. It means you annoyed me because you didn't take my advice to heart. And that makes your questions on Meta and my answer pointless as you didn't learn a single thing.

Comment: With respect, you have 25.6k reputation, while I have 130. Do you suppose me to behave exactly like you, just because you asked it..! Where does the concept of regular hard work go? I have to work years regularly to edit a post of your level.

Comment: I used to have 130 as well ...and I posted on meta when I was well beyond that rep level.

Comment: Were you same, as you are now..! with experience and help from others, you are, what you are now.
I tried my best to follow the rules, that he proposed me. Is there something else better than a best try. I tried my best to follow them, not just some random edition of every post, without care or concern.>!

Comment: Sure, just be a bit more careful and receptive to feedback. You made some mistakes, learn from it, Don't make a case to rectify your actions.

Comment: @Syed Everyone here was once new. We don't expect you to never make mistakes, but we do expect you to learn from the mistakes you've made when they are pointed out to you. The problem comes when constructive feedback and criticism is not taken to heart.

Comment: I wanted to know, the consequences of participating in a meta, and i think reading this post will help others guys, before posting in meta.